# JavaFX: Is Duration ignored in some cases?

Tags: javafx

I'm writing the code to move the ball using the Timeline. In the following code the Duration(1000) works fine:

```
    private void moveTheBall(double currentCenterX){

    timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);

    KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(ball.centerXProperty(), 0);
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), keyValue);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);

    timeline.play();

}
```

But when I use different constructor of KeyFrame to manually move the ball, I had to use the Duration(5) to move the ball at the same speed:

```
 private void moveTheBall(double currentCenterX){


    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(new Duration(5), event -> {

        if (currentBallX > BALL_MOVEMENT_INCREMENT) {
            currentBallX -= BALL_MOVEMENT_INCREMENT;
        } else {
            timeline.stop();
        }

        ball.setCenterX(currentBallX);
    });

    timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    timeline.play();

}
```

I understand that when I implement certain actions in the event handler they may take longer, but why not providing a KeyFrame constructor that doesn't require specifying the Duration object that doesn't work anyway?

Comment: My wild guess would be to check the logic written inside the inner class lambda expression. Duration worka as it should, irrespective of where it is used.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha But you see all the the logic in my second example. I just change the centerX coordinate of the ball, that's all.

Comment: It is difficult to suggest anything without a concrete example. May be if you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it can help debug your problem.

Comment: The current version of the code is here https://github.com/yfain/Java4Kids_NoStarchPress_code/tree/master/PingPong/src/pong.

Pressing S on the keyboard will start the ball movement.

To try the previous version of the moveTheBall() you'd need to use the PingPongController_v4 in the pingpong.fxml. Thanks.

Comment: @YakovFain You may be interested in [animated transitions using ReactFX](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/13/animated-transitions-made-easy.html). The example in that blog post demonstrates how to move a circle, either at constant duration or at constant speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you specify a `KeyFrame` with a timepoint of 1 second and a `KeyValue` that sets `centerX` to `0`. This means when the animation runs, it will interpolate the `centerX` property value so that it finishes at 1 second with it equal to `0`.

In the second example, you don't specify a `KeyValue`, but you specify a `KeyFrame` with a timepoint of 5 milliseconds and an action to take at that timepoint; namely decrementing the `centerX` property by some fixed amount. You also make the animation run indefinitely, but stop it manually when you get to the target value. This means the action will be invoked every 5 milliseconds.

Note that in this case you are effectively hard-coding a frame rate of 200Hz (one frame every 5 ms).  You won't achieve this frame rate as the target frame rate of JavaFX is currently 60Hz; your updates will be coalesced into a single update each frame. If a later release of JavaFX had significantly higher frame rate, your animation might not be as smooth as your first version.

The reason the ball moves at the same speed in the second example as the first is just due to some math (based on some values you haven't shown us). In the second example, your event handler is invoked once every 5ms, so 200 times in a second. So I am guessing that the starting value for `centerX` is equal to `200 * BALL_MOVEMENT_INCREMENT`.

Comment: The starting value of the centerX is 365 (I posted the code on GitHub, the link is in the comment to the OP ). The BALL_MOVEMENT_INCREMENT = 5.

Comment: @James_D Your answer explains the behavior of my code. So basically, the Duration can have two different meanings depending on its use:
1. The length of the  time interval to reach the target
2. The interval between the attempts to run the code specified in the  the event handler.

This was not explained in the javadoc. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really two different meanings. The `KeyFrame` has a timepoint, specified by the `Duration`. It optionally has an `onFinished` handler and has zero or more `KeyValue`s. An animation will interpolate the values of all the `KeyValue`s between the start and the timepoint, and when the timepoint is reached, will invoke the `onFinished` handler, if one exists. The [`KeyFrame` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) say this, though the description is pretty terse.